# connection between spell correction, language selection, predictive text, and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, text-prediction, spell-check

Can someone please explain to me the android conceptual model between

1. language selection
2. spell correction
3. predictive text
4. keyboard

I.e., is it the responsibility of the keyboard app to support multiple language, provide dictionaries, and analyze the sentences you type to try to predict the next word?  Or is the keyboard just responsible for noticing where your fingers touch and providing characters to another program which does the checking and prediction?

Answer (score 0):

In most android keyboards, the keyboard app has its own dictionary and language packs. It records the language in the keyboard's data base. Spelling correction and predictive text depends on the language data, the script of the language that was selected and your most used words and sentences. It remembers your sentences or any new words that you type and try to help you complete your sentence by using the previous record of your conversation or anything.